# Change UILocalNotification count at the panel

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

i have meet the problem: when i send a UILocalNotification as：

```
UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (alarm) {
    alarm.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    alarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    alarm.alertBody ="This is 1 message";

    if (object) {
        NSDictionary *infoDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:object forKey:objectkey];
        alarm.userInfo = infoDic;

    }


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:alarm];
```

you can see the code:when i send the notication twice you can receive the message twice:
"This is 1 message"
"This is 1 message"
at the panel of mobile.  i want to  not change the  alarm.alertBody content,but when i receive the message twice,i can merge the two meaasge
"This is 1 message"
"This is 1 message"  as one "there are  two messages" on the panel . if  i can finished the task,if yes,what api can i use?
     in android status info and panel info is different,but i think iOS only one alert body,at status and panel is the same am i right?

Edit: i donot know why give me -2,my quetion is easy? or other? the answer not my need.

edit 2:  i describe my need. when user receive different 1 message form 15 people,it come one by one,so i cannot give it [NSString stringWithFormat:@"there are %d messages",count],i only give it "there is 1 message",but when user open the panel,i only show" there are 15 message",can cannel 14 "there is 1 message". answer 1,give me answer is :at status "there is 15 message" ,but not people give me so many message,people only give me 1 message

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to schedule the notification.
Create an array for the alert msgs use counter +1 for adding new alert each time.
Then you can schedule the local notification on a particular date as you want some thing like this would help:

```
- (void)scheduleNotification:(NSDate*)showDate withMsg:(NSString*)msg
{
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        //      notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];

        //setting the fire dat of the local notification
        notif.fireDate = showDate;//[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5];


        //setting the time zone
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        //setting the message to display
        //notif.alertBody = @"You are notified";
        notif.alertBody = msg;

        //default notification sound
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        //displaying the badge number
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1;

        //schedule a notification at its specified time with the help of the app delegate
        //        NSLog(@"Todays date:%@ Notification Date:%@",[NSDate date],showDate);

        // Displaying Button tittle
        notif.alertAction = @"Show me";

        //      //setting the values in dict of local notification  
        //      NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:_serverMsg
        //                                                             forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
        //      notif.userInfo = userDict;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];

    }

}
```

Comment: i want  to merge two message.when first receive "this is 1 message",on the second receive"this is 1 message" also,but when you open the panel you only see"there are two message". your methods only change the receive message,but not change panel message

Comment: Its might be because you are not cancelling the previously scheduled notification try [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];  
 Please try to send call this function when your all the msg are bind, you may use a mutable string for that.

Comment: how to get the previously notification? i cannot use cancelAllLocalNotifications

Comment: i want to receive at the status message is different from the panel

Comment: you can cancel one notification by using an array and check the notifications using loop or some thing. `-(void)cancelLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);`

Comment: but cannot modify the alertbody info

Comment: when receive the nofitication at status you see"this is 1message",but i want to open the panel you can see"there are  5 messages"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20678/discussion-between-pengwang-and-hddeveloper)

Comment: thats what i said first, use a counter, when you schedule a  notification, count++ after scheduling.. cancel previous notification and then create a new notification with msg body `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"there are %d messages",count];`
And reset count in appdelegate as you are setting
'notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0; //[[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]'
Hope this may work for you.

Comment: you cannot understand my question and why i need the info.when user receive 1 message form 15 people,it come one by one,so i cannot give it [NSString stringWithFormat:@"there are %d messages",count],i only give it "there is 1 message",but when user open the panel,i only show" there are 15 message"